# F# has a discrepancy between func `lambda` and `lambda` |> func

Tags: f#

I'm using the FSharpPlus library and there is a discrepancy between

```
#r "nuget: FSharpPlus"
open FSharpPlus

memoizeN (fun x y -> x,y)       // error FS0073: internal error: recursive class hierarchy (detected in TypeFeasiblySubsumesType), ty1 = MemoizeN

(fun x y -> x,y) |> memoizeN    // OK
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way to use the former?

Comment: There's something with [type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-inference). Sometimes you need to switch function and argument in order to make it work if you don't type things explicitly

Comment: I'm looking for a more detailed explanation

Comment: This is likely a compiler bug. I suggest you report this in the [dotnet/fsharp](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues) repo on GitHub, but please search for duplicates first. There are many issues related to FS0073, so it can take some time to research them for duplicates. If you prefer not to do that research, I'll be happy to do it for you, and I'll link to this SO issue if I find that an issue should be created there.

Comment: Also, if you or me or someone else report this on GitHub, it's nice to also answer this question with a brief explanation and a link to the GitHub issue. If there already is a suitable GitHub issue, that can also be used as an answer here.

Comment: Well, I did search thoroughly for duplicates, and there seems to be none. This is up for grabs for anybody that want to make that report. I'll do it within a day if nobody else takes it.

Comment: I reported it here : https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the lambda, this is kind of a corner type inference case.

F# type inference works from left to right, so in some cases it's not able to infer the correct type of a generic function, unless the type information of its argument is already inferred.

A simpler case could be this:

```
let x = (fun lst -> lst.Length) [0]
```

Comment: Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I would say it's a known limitation of F# type inference.

Comment: That's interesting because I notice that intellisense does show the correct type on mouse hover even though the red squiggles are there.

Comment: Yes, intellisense does multiple passes. F# type checker is single pass, possibly in order to speed up compiler.